# How to make pyInstaller work

Tags: python, pip

Ok, so I have been through many of the different fixes, and I still can't get it to work. In python command line I run the

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

it gives me a syntax error, so I run the line of code to set my path, and pip is in my scripts, it still doesn't work. I am not sure how to get this to work. pip is installed but it still refuses to install pyinstaller, saying it has a syntax error. Upon looking this up I find you need to set the path, so I do so, but that does not fix the problem, Help would be very nice!

Comment: What kind of syntax error is it giving you? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: pip is a command to run at your **OS** command line. For us to be able to help, you need to be very explicit about 1) the steps you took and 2) the errors you're getting. Open up a new terminal and type the commands that you are typing. Also copy and paste the error messages that you're getting. If it's a Python traceback, probably copy/paste the *entire* message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run that command *from the command line* (the terminal), not the Python interpreter.

You may think if something is written *in Python* or *for Python* it must be run from the interpreter. Well, *not necessarily*. Speaking of `pip` or `easy_install`, they must be run from the terminal.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OPs question.

Comment: @WayneWerner, well, I've seen many similar questions and always the answer was to run `pip` from within the terminal. Let's see whether it helps in this case.